# How to do a t.test on a linear model for a given value of beta1?

Tags: r, statistics

```
data("hprice2")
reg1 <- lm(price ~ rooms + crime + nox, hprice2)
summary(reg1)

Call:
lm(formula = price ~ rooms + crime + nox, data = hprice2)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-18311  -3218   -772   2418  39164 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -19371.47    3250.94  -5.959 4.79e-09 ***
rooms         7933.18     407.87  19.450  < 2e-16 ***
crime         -199.70      35.05  -5.697 2.08e-08 ***
nox          -1306.06     266.14  -4.907 1.25e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6103 on 502 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5634,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5608 
F-statistic: 215.9 on 3 and 502 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Question 1.

Run two alternative (two-sided) t-tests for: H0: B1 = 8000

```
predict(reg1, data.frame(rooms=8000, crime = -199.70, nox =  -1306.06), interval = .99)
```

Report your t-statistic and whether you reject or fail to reject the null at 90, 95, and/or 99 percent confidence levels.

Comment: please include the code in your question.. no pictures please.. it's not reproducible and really hard to read. I can definitely answer it for you if you provide the information

Comment: sorry, I fixed my question

Answer (score 2):

I suppose by beta1 you mean `rooms` in this case. Your t.test in the summary is tested against beta0 = 0, you can see from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Slope_of_a_regression_line):

[image]

so using the example of nox:

```
tstat = (-1306.06 - 0)/266.14  
[2] -4.907417
```

And p.value is

```
2*pt(-abs(tstat),502)
[2] 1.251945e-06
```

the null hypothesis in your case will be 8000 and you test rooms = 8000:

```
tstat = (7933.18 - 8000)/407.87
2*pt(-abs(tstat),502)
```

You can also use linearHypothesis from cars to do the above:

```
library(car)
linearHypothesis(reg1, c("rooms = 8000"))
```

Comment: Thank you stupidwolf I've been up all night trying to figure this out ^>^ im so happy

Comment: cool.. hope it frees up some time for learning more coding :)